# Can you suggest an email client that I can install into an already exisitng CMS?

Tags: php, email, content-management-system, imap

I'm looking for the best way to integrate a "professional" email address into my clients CMS (ie: info@website.com as opposed to website@gmail.com).

Right now I have two clients with sites/email accounts hosted with Godaddy.  Right now if any emails are sent to them, the messages will be forwarded to their private email.  They could of course log into Godaddy and navigate to their email from there but I'm looking for an option that is more user-friendly.  Preferably something I could integrate into my already existing CMS.

I do some freelance web design and so far I've pretty much made everything by hand.  I've built a very basic CMS that my clients can use to update their blog and other content via PHP/SQL.  It's light-weight and I like how I know every square inch of code.  So I'm not looking to scrap everything for a new CMS (It's all based on php/mysqli insert/update/delete with some javascript/jquery sprinkled in.  I dont want to adopt wordpress or joomla to do that for me).

On the other hand, I don't want to re-invent the wheel building my own email client.  From what I've read that would not be worth my time (and don't know anything about IMAP etc).

So are there any good open-source scripts or software that don't require me to build the entire site around this one task??

Comment: So are you just looking for a web based email client? Like http://roundcube.net/ or http://squirrelmail.org/ ?

Comment: Basically, I'm looking for the best way to let my clients send mail from their email accounts (info@examplesite.com).  I've never heard of those two but i'm looking at them now

Comment: Either of them will work, squirrelmail is very lightweight but very simple, roundcube is much larger but will behave much more like gmail or another email client you are used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to edit some UI bindings to your needs and possible business logic, as your framework is probably unique. However, you're right: avoid IMAP like the plague. IMAP isn't the issue - email format is. An RFC is all fine and good until people stop following it.

Sadly, there are also very few actual IMAP libraries around, so every route has thorns.

You'll most likely either have to strip an IMAP reader/interpreter lib from an existing mail client (Roundcube has a particularly decoupled one. I know it, I've stripped it out once), or use a standalone (all badly documented, the best one being https://github.com/cnizzdotcom/php-imap ).

From there, it's a matter of building the actual message-display process, which is a long and tedious (but not so difficult) task. Consider building it as both plain html and RESTful API endpoint so you can easily enrich it with JS interactions.

For the UI itself, whatever picks your fancy. There's no open component out there.